# Is decoding of PKCS8 key from Base64 encoded ASN1 structure fault tolerant?

Tags: android, bouncycastle, asn.1, spongycastle

I'm using Spongy Castle library to encode my users private key (PKCS8) into an ASN1 entity and afterwards as Base64 encoded string into a QR code.

One of my colleagues found out that it's possible to change some characters in the Base64 string without damaging the private key.
Does the ASN1 format or PKCS8/DER format have some fault tolerance implemented?

```
//final String encoded = "MIGcAgEBB........lGEOPD2o+H59Qyl"; // original
final String encoded = "MIGcAgEBB........lGEOPD2oXXXXXXX"; // changed!

// decode Base64
final byte[] buffer = Base64.decode(encoded);

// decode ASN1
final ASN1Primitive primitive = ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(buffer);
final ASN1Sequence asn1Sequence = ASN1Sequence.getInstance(primitive);
// read from ASN1
final BigInteger version = ASN1Integer.getInstance(asn1Sequence.getObjectAt(0)).getValue();
final byte[] keyBytes = DEROctetString.getInstance(asn1Sequence.getObjectAt(1)).getOctets();

// get private key from bytes
final PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
final PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
```

Answer (score 0):

[PKCS#8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5958) is a fairly general container for private keys. Some of the underlying private key structures that it may wrap can contain redundant data. In particular a PKCS#1 [RSAPrivateKey](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.2) has several redundant fields which can be recalculated if necessary. The last 3 fields are completely superfluous. Now, what happens when the consuming software receives a PKCS#8 structure with incorrect or modified data is up to that piece of software.

PKCS#8 does have an encrypted private key info option which can be used to provide anti-tamper cryptography with the correct choice of protection algorithms. If your private key information is ever in an environment where intentional or accidental modification is a legitimate threat then you must take measures to mitigate that threat.